# Show that a sequence of operators converges strongly to $I$ but not by norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

$\textbf{The question is as follows:}$

> > Suppose the sequence of operators $A_n:\ell_2 \to \ell_2$ given by 
> >     $$A_n x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n, 0 ,0, \ldots)$$
> >     Prove that $A_n$ converges strongly to $I$ but not by norm.

Sorry I saw some where a solution for this question as follows:

Define the projection $P_n:X \to X$ for $X = \ell_2(\mathbb N)$ by $P_n(x_1, \ldots , x_n, x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}, \ldots )= (x_1, \ldots , x_n, 0, 0,\ldots )$. Then we have $\|P_n - P_m\| = 1$ for $m\neq n,$ so $(P_n)$ does not converges uniformly.

Nevertheless, if $x \in \ell_2(\mathbb N)$ is any fixed vector, we have $P_n x \to x$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$. Thus $P_n \to I$ strongly.

> Everything is Okay with this proof else than $\|P_n - P_m\|=1$! I cannot understand how can it work?
>
> Can someone please let me know how can it be?
>
> Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please point out specifically what is the problem?

Comment: @uniquesolution Thanks! I mean how can we have $\|P_n - P_m\|_{\ell_2} = 1?$ I think it is not correct?

Comment: Suppose $m > n$, and find a unit vector $x$ such that $P_m x = x$ and $P_nx =0$. Then $\|P_m-P_n\| \ge \|P_mx-P_nx\|=\|x\|=1$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Let $n>m$. Then if $x$ is the vector which is 1 everywhere except the $m+1$ place, $P_m x=0$ and $P_n x=x$ (can you see that?). Thus, $(P_n-P_m)(x)=x$ and by the definition of the norm operator 
$$\lVert P_n-P_m \rVert =\sup \frac{(P_n-P_m)(y)}{\lVert y\rVert}\geq \frac{(P_n-P_m)(x)}{\lVert x\rVert} =1$$

Comment: Many thanks! Yes, now I see that.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: What do you mean by 1 everywhere? is it in $\ell^2$?